# Just select one group

Tags: modeling

I have made a chair that contains several objects that I have made into one group. Then later I have copied that group because I want more chairs in my scene.

But when I want to move or remove one of the chairs, I click on one object in the that group and press SHIFT + G and then select Group. But then all groups (Chairs) are selected! Is there a way to just select the group I clicked on?

Comment: When you duplicated the chairs, you might have just duplicated the objects into the same group. Try removing the second group of chairs from the group then adding them to their own group.

Comment: Is there any reason in using groups then? Their usage is mostly for convenience which means you add objects to a group and then avoid adding objects themselves, rather than group instance instead (Shift+A > Group).

Comment: So, the solution is to duplicate the first group and then remove from all groups and then create a new group for that chair? And then do the same thing for each chair?

Comment: That depends on what you'd like ot do. If you want to make parts of a chair to be present in only one group, then you select original chair parts (without their duplicates), add them to a group, delete all their duplicates and add a group instance from Shift+A menu. I'm not sure what is your desired result. See https://docs.blender.org/manual/ja/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/relations/groups.html

Comment: The group that an object belongs to is a property, and that property is copied into any copied objects. You don't need to update the group of each object individually, you can change one, then select all the rest (with the active object being the one in the new group) then press Ctrl+shift+G